# Which web hosting provider is ideal for ASP.NET MVC 4 site running over SQL Server 2008 R2 database?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, web-hosting

I am seeking for an advice to deploy my ASP.NET MVC website on a web hosting provider.

I want to deploy one site which will have following three applications:

- ExternalSite_Web: A website built upon ASP.NET MVC 4 on .NET Framework 4
- Service_WCF: A WCF service that's been consumed by ExternalSite_Web and it uses Entity Framework 5, and SQL Server 2008 R2 database.
- InternalSite_Web: A website built upon ASP.NET MVC 4 on .NET Framework 4

My questions are as follow:

1. Can I deploy all these 3 site under one domain?
2. Which web hosting provider can give me easy deployment options for publishing these range of applications.
3. Which is the best and economic web hosting provider to suit my needs with best performance to end-users?
4. At initial level I will be fine with 1 GB of space.. whereas I anticipate I will need around 5 GB of space including sql database as the site users grow.

Any advice on this much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you select a provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your question is that "economic web hosting provider" means different things to different people.  So, I will attempt to answer based on my experience with a range of tastes and perspectives.

Except for the service, I think [winhost](http://www.winhost.com/) will work.  I have hosted a few client applications there and they have been pleased with the cost/value.

If you need to run the service and want a reliable provider (though more expensive), I also like [the sba](http://webservices.thesba.com/).  If you get a virtual server you can meet your needs at a fraction of the cost of hosting it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Here’s my List.

SmarterASP.NET

ASPHOSTPORTAL

Accu Web Hosting

Interserver.net

A2Hosting

You can read the detailed comparison here => [Best Windows Host](https://dottutorials.net/best-fast-cheap-windows-hosting-asp-net-core/)